# Undefined index: formSubmit

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm building a form to be used to input data into a database.  I have the basic form and validation built (I think).  When I try testing it on my server/domain I keep getting the error undefined Index: Form Submit.  I'm certain it's something minor, but I can't find my error.  An extra set of eyes looking at this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylesheet.css">
<title>Tech Order Department.html</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />

</head>

<body>

<!--Designing my form-->

<h2>New Projects</h2>

<br>

<?php
  if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
  {
    $varMovie = $_POST['formProject'];
$varMovie = $_POST['formClient'];
$varMovie = $_POST['formLastName'];
$varMovie = $_POST['formDateReceived'];
  }
?>


<form action="myform.php" method="post">

       Project:<br>
       <input type="text" name="Project">
<br>
       Client:<br>
       <input type="text" name="Client">

<br>
       Last Name:<br>
       <input type="text" name="LastName">

<br>
       Date Received:<br>
       <input type="text" name="DateReceived">


  <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">

</form>   

<?php
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
{
  $errorMessage = "";

  if(empty($_POST['formProject'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a project name!</li>";
  }
  if(empty($_POST['formClient'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a client name!</li>";
  }
  if(empty($_POST['formLastName'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter the tech writer name!</li>";
  }
  if(empty($_POST['formDateReceived'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter the date received!</li>";
  }


  $varMovie = $_POST['formProject'];
  $varName = $_POST['formClient'];
  $varMovie = $_POST['formLastName'];
  $varMovie = $_POST['formDateReceived'];

  if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
  {
    echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
    echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
  } 

}

?>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change :

```
  if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
```

To :

```
  if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) && $_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
```

When you're using form, you should **ALWAYS** verify at least once posted that your fields are set.

**For example :**

We have this quick form :

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="POST">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

First note that on the  I've put two attributes :

- action : Which is where the form will be send
- method : Which is how the form will be send

There are two inputs "firstname","lastname" and a button submit.

Let's say that on the "action_page.php" you want to display : "Hello, firstname lastname".

You could just do the following :

```
<?php 
   echo 'Hello, '.$_POST['firstname'].' '.$_POST['lastname'];
?>
```

And that will print out what you want.
But in the case where those fields would be empty that would create "*Undefined Index*"...

So to be sure that you won't be using variables that doesn't exist you should do the following :

```
<?php 

  //First we create an array that will errors if they occurs
  $error = array();

  //Then we test if firstname exist
  if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
     //if it does we can assign him.
     $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  }else{
     //if it doesn't that's an error.
     $error[] = 'Please enter your firstname';
  }

  //Then we test if lastname exist
  if (isset($_POST['lastname'])) {
     //if it does we can assign him.
     $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  }else{
     //if it doesn't that's an error.
     $error[] = 'Please enter your lastname';
  }

  //In the end we check if we have any error stocked:
  if(empty($error)) {
     //if it's empty we have all our required data to display our echo
   echo 'Hello, '.$firstname.' '.$lastname;
  }else{
     //else let's show the error
     print_r($error);
  }
?>
```

This way we handle any possible "Undefined Index" before they occur and we are sure that our data will return something or at least have an error related.

Comment: I tried your solution.  It cleared the error I was having, but now it's throwing the same errors in the variables I've selected, i.e. $varMovie = $_POST['formProject'];

Comment: Before using a $_POST var, you should always check if this var is set or not empty otherwhile might create a bunch of undefined index

Comment: This is my first time using forms so I'm still learning some of this.  How can I check these variables?

Comment: You can use if(isset($_POST['something'])) before actually using it, just give me a sec i'll edit my post to give you a better example

Comment: Post updated let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: no sweat.  I appreciate the help.   I'm looking at the array now and when I load the page, I see this: Array ( [0] => Please enter your firstname [1] => Please enter your lastname )   It's in the error checking portion of the array.  Not sure why it's called out like that.  BTW, that's the basic form I started with haha.

Comment: If your fields are filled and you're receiving error, that's wierd can you please put a var_dump($_POST); on the first line of this code and tell me what you're receiving ?

Comment: Actually I'm getting that prior to entering any data.  That's what I'm puzzled by it.

Comment: If you're not entering any data, that's the intended behavior, since you've no data in your $_POST, firstname and lastname are undefined which is why you're receiving an error, fill the inputs, submit your form and it should be fine

Comment: Shouldn't the error check take place after I hit submit though?

Comment: I bet your form and your error check are on the same file, right ?

Comment: Yes they are.  All the examples I've researched had it set up that way, however, none of them were in array's though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94440/discussion-between-nirnae-and-tony).

Answer (score 1):

For check if there was a `POST` action :-

```
if (!empty($_POST))
```

or

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code , check this

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylesheet.css">
        <title>Tech Order Department.html</title>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>New Projects</h2>
        <?php
        if ($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") {
            $varMovie = $_POST['formProject'];
            $varMovie = $_POST['formClient'];
            $varMovie = $_POST['formLastName'];
            $varMovie = $_POST['formDateReceived'];
        }
        ?>
        <form action="myform.php" method="post">
            Project:<br>
            <input type="text" name="Project">
            <br>
            Client:<br>
            <input type="text" name="Client">
            <br>
            Last Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="LastName">
            <br>
            Date Received:<br>
            <input type="text" name="DateReceived">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
        </form>   
        <?php
        
       if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) && $_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") {
            $errorMessage = "";
            if (empty($_POST['formProject'])) {
                $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a project name!</li>";
            }
            if (empty($_POST['formClient'])) {
                $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a client name!</li>";
            }
            if (empty($_POST['formLastName'])) {
                $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter the tech writer name!</li>";
            }
            if (empty($_POST['formDateReceived'])) {
                $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter the date received!</li>";
            }
            $varMovie = $_POST['formProject'];
            $varName = $_POST['formClient'];
            $varMovie = $_POST['formLastName'];
            $varMovie = $_POST['formDateReceived'];
            if (!empty($errorMessage)) {
                echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
                echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Ananata Prasad Loda I tried your code but I'm getting  Undefined index: formSubmit  here: if ($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") {